# Maven - skip execution step with a flag?

Tags: maven

I have this code in my `pom.xml` (inside a `<plugin>`)

```
                <execution>
                    <id>npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>ci</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>Run Unit Tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run test</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

Is there a way i can pass a flag when i run `mvn clean install` that will skip the `Run Unit Tests` execution step?

Comment: depends on the plugin. What plugin are using?

Comment: `frontend-maven-plugin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably do the following.

1. Define under `<properties>` something like `<run.unit.tests.skip>false</run.unit.tests.skip>`
2. Add `<skip>${run.unit.tests.skip}</skip>` to the configuration of the execution.
3. Then `mvn clean install -Drun.unit.tests.skip=true` would the command line call.